# File upload HttpClient -- no file in selected folder

Tags: java, php, android, http, upload

I'm using loopj/android-async-http lib to upload files in my server.

My Android code:

```
File myFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(SettintsActiviy.this, selectedImage));

RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("uploaded_file", myFile);
    params.put("name", "adfadfa");
    params.put("tmp_name", "fadfadfa");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post("http://localhost:8081/html/upload.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
        System.out.println("statusCode "+statusCode);//statusCode 200
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

    }
});
```

My upload.php

```
<?php

$file_path = "/images/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}?>
```

Log Android result:

```
06-09 22:19:53.192 18958-18958/br.md.screamchat V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 205268 from 221141 (93%)
06-09 22:19:53.192 18958-18958/br.md.screamchat V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 209364 from 221141 (95%)
06-09 22:19:53.192 18958-18958/br.md.screamchat V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 213460 from 221141 (97%)
06-09 22:19:53.192 18958-18958/br.md.screamchat V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 217556 from 221141 (98%)
06-09 22:19:53.192 18958-18958/br.md.screamchat V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 221103 from 221141 (100%)
06-09 22:19:53.193 18958-18958/br.md.screamchat V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 221105 from 221141 (100%)
06-09 22:19:53.193 18958-18958/br.md.screamchat V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 221141 from 221141 (100%)
06-09 22:19:56.252 18958-18958/br.md.screamchat V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 7 from 7 (100%)
06-09 22:19:56.252 18958-18958/br.md.screamchat I/System.out: statusCode 200
```

But when I open the selected folder does not have file.